# How i can still use Accept in while loop to accept new clients,but also want to turn of the server whenever i want

Tags: c++, sockets, mfc

I have a homework about FTP using CSocket in C++.I use Mfc Dialog-based as interface for my application.Using multithreading to handle multi-clients (1 server - many clients). I use a button called "Listen".Everytime i hit the button,server start to listen. But the problem here,i put the Accecpt in a loop to handle muti-clients (each clients will go in a seperate thread), but now i cannot close the server-dialog whenever i want.It stucks in the "Listen" button forever.Can you give me some suggest to make it works.I did some research myself.I tried some techniques but it didn't work.
Thank you.

Please dont tell me about Select or Poll, I am using Windows not Linux.
I want to keep CSocket ,not Winsock. I tried to close listen in another thread ,but it didn't work.

````
    void CServerDlg::OnBnClickedListen()
    {
        // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
        if (listen.Create(PORT, SOCK_STREAM, _T("127.0.0.1")) == 0) {
            showMessage("Failed to init socket");
            listen.GetLastError();
            return;
        }
        else {
            if (listen.Listen(1) == FALSE) {
                showMessage("Can't listen to the port");
                listen.Close();
                return;
            }

        }
        int cnt = -1;
        CSocket* client;

        while (1)
        {
            client = new CSocket();
        if (listen.Accept(*client))
            {
                cnt++;
                char * id = Converter::StringToChar(Converter::NumberToString(*client));
                clients.push_back(client);
                ClientId.push_back(id);

                showMessage("Found a connection with client " + Converter::CharToString(id));

                /*
                         Thread here
                */
                threads.push_back(thread(&CServerDlg::ThreadProc, this, cnt));
            }
            else break;
        }
        listen.Close();

            for (int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++)
            {
                if (clients[i] != NULL)
                {
                    clients[i]->Close();
                }
            }
            clients.clear();

    }
    ```
    void CServerDlg::OnBnClickedCancel()
    {
        // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
            // i want every time i click 'cancel; button  theaplcaton will clsoe
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Don't ever have an infinite loop in an event-based GUI program. That stops *all* the event handling and the program will become unresponsive and can seem to be frozen. MFC is asynchronous with its GUI and events, and so are the sockets. You can set it up so you get a call-back when a new connection is made on the passive socket, or when a connection have something to read, just like the `OnButtonClick` events you get from the UI, and with no threads needed. Please try to read more about it and the socket classes you use.

Comment: And if you use event-handling, then it should be very easy to do what you want: In the `OnBnClickedListen` function you create the listening socket, set it up for the asynchronous events, and then just return. Then the `OnBnClickedCancel` function closes that listening socket.

Comment: You may be looking for [`CAsyncSocket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/casyncsocket-class). It works similar to `CSocket`, but is asynchronous. You derive your own class from it, call `Accept` which returns immediately, and eventually a virtual function `OnAccept` is called to let you know a connection has arrived.